# MVVMCross Databiding v3

Tags: xamarin.android, mvvmcross

Could Anyone get me a sample databinding using converters that work with mvvmcross v3? on Xamarin.Android?
Thanks your help is really appreciated

Answer (score 2):

The ValueConversion set of samples should give you quite a lot to work with https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross-Tutorials/tree/master/ValueConversion

Comment: Thanks Stuart, the samples really helped a lot ;-)

Comment: Thanks - I thought it was a good question too.... maybe just phrase it with slightly more words next time and the moderators won't close it? Maybe...

Comment: Yes, i was hungry for solution at the time of writing, next time i will be more "verbose" ;-), so everyone will understand better.